# Windows presentation foundation host crashes

Tags: wpf, windows, internet-explorer-8, presentation

we are using a saas application that uses WPF. it usually work fine on every browser we use
but one of our user recently was transferred  to a different office and from that day he gets an error on IE 8 about WPF encountered a problem and the application crashes. same for the other browsers.

could it be connected to the network he wired to?

Comment: How does IE get a WPF error?   Is this an XPAB?

Comment: yes its xbap and the error is: Windows Presentation Foundation Host Has Encountered a Problem and needs to be closed

Answer (score 0):

I am Exactly getting the same error.

[image]

A some of the forums suggest registry access problem but when I run the tool it says no[image] problem with access.

I guess my website response is XML which is some how not been interpreted by IE.